# Any way to retrieve system info through chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chromebook

I'm writing a chrome extension to install on a Chromebook.
This extension need to retrieve unique identifier of the chromebook.

Unique identifier may be processor id or serial number of the machine.
As long as I looked in to the api, I can't find anything.

Is it possible through any other way? NPAPI?

Comment: NPAPI certainly won't work, since ChromeOS doesn't support NPAPI.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an identifier that is unique to the machine, on a normal account, that information is not available.

However, using the [Device Attributes](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/enterprise_deviceAttributes) API (only available since Chrome 46), an unique identifier may be retrieved for the machine. But this requires that the extension be pushed down by policy. In other words, this requires that the device be *managed* by Chrome Device Management (CDM) and that the extension is pushed down from the Chrome Management Console (CMC).

If your situation doesn't meet both requirements, then your only option is to generate an ID yourself and store either in Local Storage or Chrome Local Storage as mentioned by Antony Sargent.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be sufficient to just generate a unique id on first run, say using a few calls to Math.random(), and write that into persistent storage somewhere (eg localStorage or chrome.storage.local)? Then at startup you read that in and use it?

It's sort of an explicit goal *not* to provide an extensions API to get a non-resettable unique id for a chrome install/machine.

You might be able to synthesize something based on information that is not guaranteed not to change, but in practice probably rarely changes, using the information provided by the chrome.system.storage API (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/system_storage).

Comment: Can chrome extension obtain CPU serial, or motherboard serial?

Comment: There's no extensions/apps APIs to get these, sort of by design.  It's possible you could write some native code to do this with Native Client, but I'm not sure. https://developer.chrome.com/native-client